# Not able to get Indian cities abstract from Sparql

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to get abstract using Sqarql with dbpedia datasets. 
When I am running the following query on Virtuoso,

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?abstract WHERE { 
   [ rdfs:label ?name
  ; dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract
  ] .
  FILTER langMatches(lang(?abstract),"en")
  VALUES ?name { "London"@en }
}
LIMIT 10
```

I am getting the result, however if I modify the name to say 'Gokarna' which is a south indian tourist spot, I am not getting any data. However I do see the resource page online on dbpedia for Gokarna(http://dbpedia.org/page/Gokarna,_India). What am I doing wrong? I need to get similar data for close to 800 indian places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `values`, you'd get only those that exactly match your string. For Gokarna, that would work for @de, @it, @fr, but not for @en, as there the label is different, as you can see also from the previous answer.

I would suggest to use `contains`, instead of `values`:

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?abstract WHERE { 
   [ rdfs:label ?name
  ; dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract
  ] .
  FILTER langMatches(lang(?abstract),"en")
  FILTER langMatches(lang(?name),"en")
  FILTER CONTAINS (?name, "Gokarna" )
}
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not that experience with Sqarql but as much i can see in your code and checked with dbpedia library...
it is not just Gokarna. it is "Gokarna,_India".

This should work..

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?abstract WHERE { 
   [ rdfs:label ?name
  ; dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract
  ] .
  FILTER langMatches(lang(?abstract),"en")
  VALUES ?name { "Gokarna,_India"@en }
}
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look through the DBpedia page for Gokarna, India that you linked to, you'll notice that its `rdfs:label` is "Gokarna, India". But its `foaf:name` is just "Gokarna". This would mean you should modify your query to:

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?abstract WHERE { 
   [ foaf:name ?name
  ; dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract
  ] .
  FILTER langMatches(lang(?abstract),"en")
  VALUES ?name { "Gokarna"@en }
}
LIMIT 10
```

Though this will return other Gokarnas too: Gokarna, Nepal, Gokarna, Bangladesh and Gokarna (film). If you want to remove these, you will have to figure out another filter (possibly `dbo:country dbr:India`).